# How to list number of February month between 2 timestamps using moment.js / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, calendar, momentjs, difference

How to list number of **February** month between **2 timestamps** using moment.js / Javascript ?

**end_time: 1545939000**

**start_time: 1546281000**

Comment: @lucas_7_94 how the above function is related to this question ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var dateStart = moment.unix(your_start_time).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
var dateEnd = moment.unix(your_end_time).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
var nbFebruary = 0;

while (dateEnd > dateStart || dateStart.format('M') === dateEnd.format('M')) {
   if(dateStart.format('MM') == 2)
       nbFebruary ++;
   dateStart.add(1,'month');
}
```